# How to configure sentry environments according to Android project build type (production vs staging)?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin, sentry

We are working on a Kotlin-based Android project where sentry is already up and running.
We would like to make use of the sentry [environment](https://docs.sentry.io/product/sentry-basics/environments/) tags in order to be able to distinguish between *production* and *staging* issues.

What I already know is:

1. It is possible to set a tag [programmatically](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java/issues/596). However, this is not what we are after.
2. It is possible to achieve [via the sentry-cli](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java/pull/440). However, this is not what we are after either.
3. It should be possible to use the *sentry.properties* file to configure the different environment tags. But I couldn't figure out: [which keywords](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java/issues/437) to use? [Where in the project structure](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-react-native/issues/157) to place the [different](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java/issues/716) sentry.properties [files](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java/issues/671)?
4. By looking at the javascript documentation, I suspect there should be a way to achieve it via the AndroidManifest.xml. Has anyone managed to get it working like this?

Answer (score 1):

you could also use a placeholder from the build script like:

```
<meta-data android:name="io.sentry.environment" android:value="${environment}" />
```

then define your placeholder in the build script:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        getByName("debug") {
            manifestPlaceholders = mapOf(
                "environment" to "debug"
            )
        }
        getByName("release") {
            manifestPlaceholders = mapOf(
                "environment" to "release"
            )
        }
    }
}
```

this code snippet is using kotlin kts file, so adapt it if using groovy.

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve it by using configuration, Please check below code to add tags programatically:

```
Sentry.configureScope(scope -> {
      scope.setTag("Application Name", getString(R.string.app_name));
      scope.setTag("Variant", BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE);
});
```

You will get these tags on sentry panel. ;)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set it via `AndroidManifest.xml` (I'm assuming you're using the SDK version 2.0 or later). [Here's an example](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-android/blob/42d74d9f4d90ebfb92a009c04b78cb35eb502762/sentry-samples/sentry-samples-android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L65-L66).

```xml
<meta-data android:name="io.sentry.environment" android:value="staging" />
```